# CSS - Using selectors in :not

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
.formSec .formWrap input[type="text"]:not(.counter input[type="text"]):not(other){
   width:80%;
   text-align:left;
}
```

I am trying to use :not so that all the input boxes in the formWrap class are 80% with the exception of input boxes that are contained within the .counter class.

I must keep the counter class in the parent div it cannot be applied to the input boxes and I also do not want to apply a class to the excluded input box, is this possible?

```
<div class="formSec">
<div class="formWrap counter">
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
</div>
<div class="formWrap">
<input class="other" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
</div>
<div class="formWrap">
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the HTML I need to preserve so only the second input would be 80%.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite have the HTML right see edited question

Comment: Isn' this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/gtjmbzgu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS [`:not()` negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) only accepts a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) as an argument where it should not contain another `:not()` pseudo-class or any pseudo elements. Also *[Combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators0)* are not allowed. This means that `.counter input[type="text"]` is NOT a valid argument.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) from CSS [Selectors level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/):

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

You could select `.formWrap` elements which don't have `.counter` class by `.formWrap:not(.counter)` and then target the nested `<input>` elements excluding those who have `.other` class by `input[type="text"]:not(.other)` as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/dasilo/2/edit)**

```css
.formSec .formWrap:not(.counter) input[type="text"]:not(.other) { /*
                  ^----     No spaces here     ----^              */
   width:80%;
   text-align:left;
}
```

*(Check the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25994118/1) for the old answer which was based on the old markup)*

Comment: That doesn't seem to exclude the input contained by .counter

Comment: @Kline Have you checked the demo? I don't see any issue with that. Please consider updating the demo to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Ok apologies this is part of some much larger code check this demo for the problem http://jsbin.com/sisecofaruza/1/edit

Comment: @Kline What do you mean by `.formWrap:not(.counter):not(.other)`? It won't exclude the nested `<input>` having a `.other` class. If this is what you wan't you should do it like so: http://jsbin.com/dasilo/1/edit

Comment: @Kline Updated the answer according the latest markup you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to do like this

```css
.formSec .formWrap input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%;
}
.formSec .formWrap .counter input[type="text"]{
    width:80%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="formSec">
    <div class="formWrap">
        <div class="counter">
            <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
        </div>
        <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>
```